# Javascript appendChild scrolls the user on page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create and inject a script tag into a HTML webpage through a script that's linked, e.g:

```html
<script src="/link/to/my/js-plugin.js></script>
```

Within `js-plugin.js` is a script tag I'd like to inject. However, when navigating to my webpage, I'm for some reason scrolled to the bottom of the page. I'm using `appendChild` and when removing this I'm not scrolled to the bottom of the page, my code within `js-plugin.js` is as follows:

```js
// get the head
var pageHead = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]

// create script to inject
var polyfillInject = document.createElement("script")
    polyfillInject.type = "text/javascript"
    polyfillInject.src = "https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?flags=gated%2Calways&features=default%2CArray.prototype.includes%2CArray.prototype.forEach%2Clocation.origin"

// inject our script
pageHead.appendChild(polyfillInject); // this scrolls the user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use both flags `gated` + `always` ([link to the non-minified version](https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?flags=gated%2Calways&features=default%2CArray.prototype.includes%2CArray.prototype.forEach%2Clocation.origin) ) the script contains the following test (formatted by me so it is a little easier to understand):

```
// row 6670 in v3.42.0
if (!((function(n, e, t) {
    function o() { n = !0 }

    return "onfocusin" in window
           || (t.href = "#",
               "addEventListener" in t
                   ? t.addEventListener("focusin", o)
                   : t.attachEvent("onfocusin", o),
               e.appendChild(t).focus(),   /* <- this forces the document to scroll to the bottom */
               e.removeChild(t), n)
  })(!1, document.documentElement, document.createElement("a")))) {
}
```

This tests if the browser supports the `focusin` event by adding a `<a>` element to the DOM to then call `.focus()` on this element.
And this `.focus()` call forces the browser to scroll to the element.

Example with `.focus()` call:

```js
if (!((function(n, e, t) {
    function o() {
      n = !0
    }
    return "onfocusin" in window
        || (t.href = "#",
               "addEventListener" in t
               ? t.addEventListener("focusin", o)
               : t.attachEvent("onfocusin", o),
               e.appendChild(t).focus(),
               e.removeChild(t), n)
  })
  (!1, document.documentElement, document.createElement("a")))) {
}
```

```css
div { height: 500px }
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
bar
```

Example w/o `.focus()` call:

```js
if (!((function(n, e, t) {
    function o() {
      n = !0
    }
    return "onfocusin" in window
        || (t.href = "#",
               "addEventListener" in t
               ? t.addEventListener("focusin", o)
               : t.attachEvent("onfocusin", o),
               e.appendChild(t),
               e.removeChild(t), n)
  })
  (!1, document.documentElement, document.createElement("a")))) {
}
```

```css
div { height: 500px }
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
bar
```

Comment: Can I use either gated or always, but not both?

Comment: Use whatever you need. If you need both flags then insert the script before anything else in the head. If the DOM is empty then there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: It inserts into the head using `pageHead`, but this proves not to work. I tried the non minified version with removing the "always" and "gated", however this now means my polyfill doesn't work at all, it can't find polyfill for the specified features in the URL above.

Comment: The script is added in the head but, as you can see, after the DOM has been rendered (or at least parts of it). Just add a `<script src="your polyfill url"></script>` in the head instead.

Comment: Yes, I see, I've tried this and adding my Polyfill directly to the page resolves this issue, however this isn't ideal, I need to be able to inject the Polyfill `<script>` as per my code shown above as the code is part of a larger 200 line JS plugin I'm making :) I've tried: `document.head.createElement("script")` to see if I can initially create it there rather than creating and then moving it to the `head`

Comment: The workaround I've found is to just sent the user to the top of the page using: `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: _"...part of a larger 200 line JS plugin **I'm making**"_ - Why are you including a polyfill with stuff you don't need in the first place? Only add what _your_ plugin really uses. And with _200 lines_ this won't be much.

Comment: I'm building a plugin for Android 4, most of the plugin is stripped to the basics of Javascript to ensure support. But using some more modern features like `includes` to search a string of text, is made easier with Polyfill.